# Validate currency (EUR) and sum all values

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm seeing many posts to all kinds of validation but I can't find the one for me so here's my problem:

I have a few currency fields where the user can type in any currency they want.

I have another field that shows the sum ONLY if all currency fields have the default currency: `€` (therefore the default notation is 100.000,00 - notice the comma and dot are switched compared to the English standard).
If at least one currency field has a different currency than `€` the sum field will display a hint `"Foreign currencies given"`.

I don't want the user to have to type the `€` sign every time, but if they do I don't want to get an error.

So here a few examples what should be possible to type without triggering the hint and what it should look like when the user exits the field:

- `0`, `00`, `0,0`, `0,005`
  (should turn to `0,00 €` every digit after the second decimal should be ignored)
- `999999,99 €`
  (should turn to `999.999,99 €`, biggest possible value - not more than 6 digits before and 2 after the `,`)
- `0 92, 3€`
  (should turn to `92,30 €` it should be possible to insert spaces at **any** place as long as the term is valid ignoring those)
- `21€`  (should turn to `21,00 €`)
- Optional: `23.4`(should turn to `23,40 €`), `23.004`(should turn to `23.004,00 €`) - basically when there's less than 3 digits after the dot treat it as a comma

What I did until now is this, but it's not working for `92,3` and most other examples I listed above and I don't think it's good looking in general:

```
var val = getValue(); //Here I get the string value of my input field
if (val!==null) {
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
        return val + " €";
    }
}
```

And when I go through all my currency fields to see what to put into my sum field I do this:

```
var sum = 0.0;
for(var i=0;i<currencyFieldArr.length;i++)
{
    var strValue = currencyFieldArr[i].getValue();
    if(strValue.search("€") === -1 && !currencyFieldArr[i].isNull)
    {   
        sum = "Fremdwährungen sind vorhanden";  
        break;
    }
    else if(strValue.search("€")!=-1)
    {
        var strNoComma      =   strValue.replace(',','.');
        var moneyAsNumber   =   parseFloat(strNoComma);
        sum+=moneyAsNumber;
    }
}
return sum;
```

I'm looking for a JS only solution. 
I can use regex like this (just an example - I copied from SO that works for my email validation):

```
var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
if (emailFieldValue.search(emailRegEx) === -1) {
    status = false;
}
```

Comment: You're mixing two kind of decimal separator, it can't work...

Comment: Why not? I was thinking that I could just check for lengths and if there's less than 3digits after the dot I'd treat it as a comma otherwise not. But this isn't the most important requirement, so I adjusted my question.

Comment: For future reference, you should mention that you're using the mainland European notation where `,` is for decimals and `.` is for separating thousands, instead of the English way which is the other way round. Otherwise people could get confused.

Comment: I recommend globalize.js for i18n problems.